# Flutter project not running after successful migration to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I have problem running flutter project after successful migration to null safety. I use android studio. Here is the result of flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

And here is the result of outdated dependency checks:

```
See https://dart.dev/go/null-safety-migration for a migration guide.

Analyzing project...
[-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\]
All sources appear to be already migrated.  Nothing to do.
```

However, I get an error caused by a dependency (not used directly in my pubspec.yaml, but seems one of the packages is using it and this dependency has no null safety updated). So when I try to run it from android studio I get the following output (even though dart migrate should have mention even internal packages dependencies since it might be a stopper from running):

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:tinycolor

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
lib/screens/invitations_screen.dart:115:5: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'TabController' which excludes null.
 - 'TabController' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/tab_controller.dart' ('/D:/Flutter/flutterV1.0.0.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tab_controller.dart').
    _c1?.dispose();
    ^
/D:/Flutter/flutterV1.0.0.0/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
                  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
                               ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\flutterV1.0.0.0\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutterV1.0.0.0\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

So I tried finally to run without sound-null-safety, but still an error keeps happening (I tried flutter clean --> Invalidate Caches/Restart --> pub get --> flutter run --no-sound-null-safety but still the same problem):

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        22.1s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:57596/NxvUCmZt3sM=/
```

Note: Before the last trial of restarting android studio, this last error also showed an exception  right before the "Error connecting ..." statement, and the exception was as I recall (sorry don't have the full stack trace as it doesn't show anymore):

androidx WindowInsetsCompat ---> NullPointerException on Preconditions.checkNonNull

**EDIT**
After going through dependencies in a new porject as suggested by @Taur, it turns out the problem when running without sound-null-safety was caused by flutter_typeahead dependency throwing the previously mentioned exception when I run the project:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11173): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.<clinit>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(WindowInsetsCompat.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$Api21Impl$1.onApplyWindowInsets(ViewCompat.java:4753)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:9799)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7076)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7080)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7080)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1632)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1734)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7125)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:921)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(WindowInsetsCompat.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(WindowInsetsCompat.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$BuilderImpl20.build(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1706)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$Builder.build(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1588)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$Impl.<clinit>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:748)
E/AndroidRuntime(11173):    ... 22 more
```

Comment: try to run with --no-sound-null-safety ?

Comment: hey @ikerfah .. yeah the last error is the result of running it without sound-null-safety

Comment: try to run flutter clean and run again

Comment: As I have mentioned I've also tried that but still same result

Comment: to remove null safety if your using git, checkout to the last commit before migration.

Comment: to add null safety, try to create a new project with null safety and add successively your dependencies while testing a compilation. in this way you will know the dependence that causes the problem

Comment: Thanks @Taur your suggestion was helpful .. I tried your approach by creating a new project and found that the dependency causing the problem was "flutter_typeahead" .. throwing the exception I put in the question edit .. however, seems even with previously working solutions (like using different package of flutter_keyboard_visibility), the problem remains. So, I'll see what is the best solution (or if you encountered this before and have a suggestion it would be great) and put it as an answer .. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since Dart 3, [sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety) is a requirement. See if the package that you're using has support for null safety on its latest version. If the package that you're using hasn't migrated to sound null safety, you might want to consider using workarounds or different package.